# How to get the type as a String in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, reflection, introspection

Let's say I have a type MyType defined in module My.Module. I want to have the String "My.Module.MyType" (or something like that). If I just type the String directly, I might have a typo, and if the module or type name changes, I'd like to know at compile time.

Ah, there appears there might be confusion about what I'm asking. Please look at the question carefully. Given the code:

```
module My.Module
type MyType = Int
data MyType2 = MyConstructor2 Int
main = do
  putStrLn $ theMagic MyType
  putStrLn $ theMagic MyType2
```

The output I want is:

```
My.Module.MyType
My.Module.MyType2
```

I'm looking for the type name, not the type definition. typeOf would output Int and such, that's not what I want.

Comment: What do you want to use this String for? Your program should give you compile errors if you use the wrong type name in your code.

Comment: I want a String of the type name, not the type itself. It's used to display the type name and use it to match up type names and such.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In summary, the answer is to enable template haskell and use `'` and `''`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
main = do
  putStrLn $ show 'read
```

---

If your type derives `Typeable` (which ghc can do automatically) then you can just call `typeOf` from `Data.Typeable` to get a showable representation.

If you want to get types of certain polymorphic functions, the polytypeable package on Hackage allows you to do so: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/polytypeable/0.1.0.0/doc/html/Data-PolyTypeable.html

This is a sort of insane type-level thing written by Oleg and packaged by Lennart, mind you. And it has.. quirks. The most glaring is that it can't give you (nor can I imagine how anything could, frankly) class constraint contexts. So show will be given a type of `a -> String` rather than `forall a. Show a => a -> String`.

If you need more than that, and are satisfied with doing certain things only at compile time, then using template haskell to extract type information directly from ghc is the only way to go. See `reify` and `Info` particularly: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.5.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html

Comment: Section 7.5.3 of the GHC manual documents this: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/deriving.html#deriving-typeable

Comment: @taotree. What is the type string of a polymorphic type? Do you mean vis a vis function signatures? So you can get `typeStr id = a -> a`?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have tried to reiterate the question to emphasize what I'm trying to get. typeOf is not what I want. I want the fully qualified name, not the type definition.

Comment: ok, reify took me to Name which took me to ' which is what I needed.

Comment: Note that if you use this technique with an explicitly qualified name (e.g. `show ''MyModule.MyType`), the resulting string will contain the qualified prefix (i.e. `"MyModule.MyType"`). This may or may not be what one wants. If you want the name unqualified, you can use [`nameBase :: Name -> String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.21.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:nameBase).

Answer (score 4):

You can't define theMagic as a function (since it would need a type argument), but you can get close.

```
import Data.Typeable
...
putStrLn $ show $ typeOf (undefined :: MyType)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Proxy` for this:

```
Prelude> import Data.Typeable
Prelude Data.Typeable> show $ typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy [Int])
"[Int]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Haskell does not support this for type names; only for functor names with `deriving Show`. You may be able to get type names as strings using [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell).

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing that template haskell might be required.